# Can Accelerator be harmed by space-time abilities (such as teleportation)?

Tags: a-certain-magical-index

Accelerator can control vectors with his ability "Vector Change" (sometimes also known as "Accelerator"). Is it possible for someone with a space-time ability to hurt him (e.g. by teleporting an object inside his body or moving his body parts to different places)? If not, why not?

Also, is there any other effective way of dealing damage to Accelerator (excluding magic things or Touma's imagine breaker or Kihara's way of fighting)?

Comment: I tried to improve the wording to make it a bit clearer what you are asking. If I've misunderstood what you were asking, feel free to revert it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As for teleportation, the [Railgun wiki says](http://toarumajutsunoindex.wikia.com/wiki/Accelerator):

> As of Volume 20, he is currently in Russia, where he has a brief encounter with some Russian mages, and some of Academy city's new streamlined, high-speed power suits. It is also during this encounter where we learn that his ability not only works on magic (although incompletely, as the magic is dissipated instead of redirected) but also on teleportation as well.

Supposedly, Accelerator's reflect shield works in all 11 dimensions, so as long as the teleportation is using one of those (as [Kuroko's does](http://toarumajutsunoindex.wikia.com/wiki/Shirai_Kuroko)), he'll be able to reflect it.